# Maintain checkbox state while the app is running in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I'm working in MVVM, WPF and I have a popup; inside this popup is a listbox and inside the listbox I have a checkbox. The problem is: if I uncheck an item from the list box and click outside, popup disappears; if a I click again the checkbox is reseted at its initial value (all the items become checked).

So, how can I maintain the state of the popup set and stop its resetting while the app is running ? Can I do this through XAML ?

here is the code:

```
public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isChecked = false;
    private T item;

    public CheckedListItem()
    { }

    public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set
        {
            item = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
        }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
}
```

the viewModel:

```
 private void OnApplyFiltersCommandRaised(object obj)
    {
         if (FilterElement.Contains("ClassView"))
        {
            switch (FilterElement)
            {
                case "buttonClassViewClassFilter":
                    FilteredClassViewItems.Clear();
                    FilteredFieldViewItems.Clear();
                    foreach (var filterItem in FilterItems)
                    {
                        if (filterItem.IsChecked == true)
                        {
                            FilteredClassViewItems.Add(classViewItems.First(c => c.ClassName == filterItem.Item));
                            FilteredFieldViewItems.Add(fieldViewItems.First(c => c.ClassName == filterItem.Item));

                        }
                    }

                    break;
...

public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<string>> FilterItems
    {
        get
        {
            return filterItems;
        }

        set
        {
            filterItems = value;
            SetPropertyChanged("FilterItems");

        }
    }
```

the XAML part:

```
              <ListBox x:Name="listBoxPopupContent" 
                             Height="250" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding FilterItems}" 
                             BorderThickness="0" 
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ListBox.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8" />
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </Style>

                        </ListBox.Resources>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                                          Content="{Binding Item}" 
                                          Command="{Binding DataContext.ApplyFiltersCommand, 
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, 
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                                Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should be thinking in terms of maintaining the state of the data that is the DataContext for the popup, not the state of the UI controls. Are you truly using MVVM pattern?

Comment: @Crowcoder the checkbox status is stored through my viewModel, but I don't know how to maintain the state of the date properly

Comment: @Nica This should work. Regarding your problem (on re open all your checkbox are checked) you should watch the interaction of FilterItems with the rest of your code. The property IsChecked can't change it's state alone if you don't mess with it

Comment: @DanieleSartori ok..I mess up with it in a method(ApplyFilter).. I check that if isChecked is true I fill the column correspondently.. I tried to add this in the code: <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" /> .. all items in the checkbox appeared unselected, but the state is still not maintain.. any idea ?

Comment: @Nica sorry but i don't get it. Did you solved your problem or not? Because the question was answered, and the method i've explaned is a way to keep the state of your checkboxes. If you have other problems, you can open a new question. Edit: Where did you added that setter?

Comment: @Nica Mode=OneWay in this way you are not registering in your viewmodel the changes. This mode is used only if the control is readonly. You should remove it and use the default TwoWay

Comment: @DanieleSartori My problem is not solved. I ve set the TwoWay Property, all the items are unselected, but the state of the checkbox is still not kept .. I don t know what method to try .. thanks for the patience !

Comment: @Nica you removed the code, your project is not under my eyes, so i have no clue of what your problem is. Go in debug and find where is the problem, then ask a new question, cause this is getting ridicoulus.

Comment: @DanieleSartori done editing .. sorry

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the comments and answers posted. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the state, you can just create a new view that will contain your listbox. Then your popup will be

```
<Popup>
   <views:MyListBoxview>
</Popup>
```

where views is the path where wpf can find MyListBoxview.

This is an example of how you can do MyListBoxView. First of all, add a new usercontrol to your project. Then you create:

```
<ListBox ItemSource = {Binding MyCollectionOfItem}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox IsChecked = {Binding IsItemChecked} Content = {Binding Name}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You will need to assign to this view a viewmodel that will of course implement INotifyPropertyChanged and that will have these this class defined inside it (also this class will implement INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void SetPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isItemChecked = false;
    public bool IsItemChecked
    {
        get { return isItemChecked; }
        set
        {
            isItemChecked = value;
            SetPropertyChanged("IsItemChecked");
        }
    }

    private string name ;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return Name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            SetPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

finally, the viewmodel that will represent the state of the popup will have inside this property

```
private ObservableCollection<MyItem> myCollectionOfItem = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollectionOfItem
{
    get { return myCollectionOfItem; }
    set
    {
        myCollectionOfItem = value;
        SetPropertyChanged("MyCollectionOfItem");
    }
}
```

I usually handle this kind of problem modelling properly the object that i need to bind to my controls in WPF

Comment: I store the state of my checkbox through IsChecked property.. I don't know how to make use of this though <views:MyListBoxview> ? In <views:MyListBoxview> should I include my <listbox >.. </listbox>?

Comment: the check box status is stored through my viewModel.. but I am not clear how to build the sintax prented my you

Comment: hmm.. this is very strange.. done all this steps before(except for the one with SetPropertyChanged("MyCollectionOfItem")).. but the checkbox does maintain state, if I close and reopen the checkbox, all items are selected..

Comment: You have to keep the instance of the viewmodel stored somewhere of course, then everytime you open your popup, you will re-assign it as datacontext for MyListBoxview. Also remember to set  private bool isItemChecked = false; to have all the checkbox unchecked by default

Comment: my code is similar to your example of MyListBoxView... have I missed something ?

Comment: @Nica How i am supposed to know that if you haven't posted your code?